# how to get flash's url, height, width in a HTML web page?

Tags: javascript, c++, html, flash

I am new to Web C++ programming. I am trying to use IE8's IWebBrowser2 interface to obtain a webpage's embedded flash's url, height, width information. This flash can be generated by javascript. So I did like this: from `IWebBrowser2` I got `IHTMLElementCollection`，then I iterated through the collection to get `IHTMLObjectElement2`，and finally called `get_data()` to get flash's url.

But when I tried to extract flash object's url for "http://www.abc.com", `get_data()` returned "null". Why is this?

So what's the difference between `IHTMLObjectElement2` and `IHTMLElement2`? What's the right way to obtain `IHTMLElement2` from `IWebBrower2`?

Also, anybody knows other good forums to ask web programming questions?

Your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You would grab these in Javascript. Place an ID on the element that the flash is contained in and place that ID in these:

```
document.getElementById('divID').offsetHeight
document.getElementById('divID').offsetWidth
```

Note that these are dynamic and if the flash applet changes, doesn't load, or breaks, the value can change.